# wordpress meta_query sorting on two meta values and title

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Trying to sort a CPT named 'products' using the meta values 'products_categories' and 'products_item_order' and the standard WP 'title' value.

Here's my code

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('products'),
    'posts_per_page' => "12",
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'item_cat' =>array(
                'key'     => 'products_categories',
                'value'   => serialize( strval( $cat ) ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        'item_order' => array(
            'key' => 'products_item_order',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'item_order title',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);
```

I want to sort the posts that have a 'products_item_order' first, and then list the remaining, unnumbered ones alphabetically.

The problem is the 'item_order' clause is not limiting my query to the category. If a post in category 'dog' has a 'products_item_order' value, the 'dog' post is appearing in queries for 'cat' and any other animal. What I need is a way to limit the 'item_order' clause so it only applies to posts in 'item_cat'.

Meta_query orderby changed significantly in WP 4.2+ and I can't find any examples or documentation that fill in specifically what I'm missing.

Any help most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the 'item_order' clause is not limiting my query to the category.

This is because your meta_query clauses are joined by OR. A post with 'dog' and 'products_item_order' will match even when `$cat = 'cat'` because the post will match the second disjunct.

I think you need a more complex query that spells out all the possible cases. Probably something like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'item_cat_with_order' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'item_cat_1' => array(
            'key' => 'products_categories',
            // etc
        ),
        'item_with_order' => array(
            'key' => 'products_item_order',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'item_cat_without_order' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'item_cat_2' => array(
            'key' => 'products_categories',
            // etc
        ),
        'item_without_order' => array(
            'key' => 'products_item_order',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
),
'orderby' => 'item_with_order title',
```

This logic should suffice to ensure that you're only getting the posts you want. I don't know that the 'orderby' clause is going to work exactly as you expect it to; if not, I'm guessing that WP_Query doesn't support this kind of logic (it's hard without doing an `OUTER JOIN` and then running some deduplication). To get the order right, you might need to run two separate queries and then thread the results together, or write your own SQL.